# The size folder returns 0

Tags: powershell, directory, size

I have script:

```
$array = @("c:")

    foreach ($z in $array) 
        {
            
            $FileSystemObject = New-Object -com  Scripting.FileSystemObject
            $folders = (Get-Childitem $z | ? {$_.Attributes -eq "Directory"})

            foreach ($folder in $folders)
                {
                  Write-Host "Counting for..." "$folder "
                  $FileSystemObject.GetFolder($folder.FullName).Size/1GB                            
                }
        }
```

As a result, I get something like this:

Counting for... Programs 0,0629891464486718

Counting for... Pictures_temp 1,2558867437765

Counting for... temp 13,7048118021339

Counting for... Windows 0

I don't know why I didn't get the "Program Files" or "Users" folders, for example (permission problem? I have admin rights). And why Windows returns 0. Treats system folders differently, I suppose. But is there any way to solve it?
The same thing happens with some of my network folders and I get wrong data.

Comment: Did you run PowerShell as Administrator?

Comment: `? {$_.Attributes -eq "Directory"}` can be replaced with `-Directory`

Comment: @TheMadTechnician - Yep, as admin.

@SantiagoSquarzon - Thank you. With `$folders = (Get-Childitem $z -Directory)` I get "Program Files" and "Users" folders. But like Windows folder - returns 0.

Comment: More precisely, it is different for "Program Files" and "Program Files (x86)":

Counting for ... Program Files - 0

Counting for ... Program Files (x86) - 4.50032385252416

Comment: Try adding `-Force`

Comment: You want to see the folder size one level down starting from C: right? Not sure why it's not working with `New-Object -com  Scripting.FileSystemObject` but I can show you using `Get-ChildItem` if you want.

Comment: my understanding is that the `.GetFolder()` method _exits_ when it hits any error - such as the access denied error that i get when it hits `'C:\Program Files\Windows Defender Advanced Threat Protection\Classification\Configuration'`. you will likely need to use `Get-ChildItem` with the appropriate error setting to get that info.

Comment: Yes Santiago Squarzon - one lvl down. @Lee_Dailey thank you. It looks like you are right. But to be honest, I don't really know what to do with it. I am less than a beginner in Powershell. Abraham Zinala - `$folders = (Get-Childitem $z -Directory -Force)` nothing changed.

Comment: @WebGreg - you are most welcome! glad to have helped a bit - and to see that user10722100 presented you with a solution. [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey yes, his solution is good but not great. I don't know how to assign this to the rest of the code. At the moment, I would have to use two codes - one to log errors and the other to generate the log file in the format I wanted.

Comment: @WebGreg - you can combine things in many ways. for instance, take a look at `-ErrorVariable`. if you need more detail, please open a new Question since that _is_ new. [*grin*]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do have consistent result with this. Pay attention it outputs errors in case of access denied to child items. Run as admin or either handle $error to discard those properly.

```
$array = @("c:")
foreach ($z in $array) 
{   Get-Childitem $z | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer } | ForEach-Object {
        Write-Host "  for..." "$_"
        ((Get-ChildItem $_.FullName -Recurse | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).Sum)/1Gb
    }
}
```

or, to respect initial script

```
$array = @("c:")
foreach ($z in $array) 
{   $folders = (Get-Childitem $z | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer })
    $folders | ForEach-Object {
        Write-Host "  for..." "$_"
        ((Get-ChildItem $_.FullName -Recurse | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).Sum)/1Gb
    }
    Clear-variable -name folders -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
}
```

Comment: This is it! thank you very much :D The c drive was just an example. The problem was with network resources. Thanks to listing the errors, I already know that the problem was too long path to files for some directories. Now I need to figure out how to redirect errors to the log file and I have what I wanted.

Comment: I will log errors with the code below

`$Error | ForEach-Object {
    $errorWrite = $_.Exception.Message
    $data = Get-Date -UFormat "%Y/%m/%d %R %A:"
    Write-Host "$data","$errorWrite" *>> C:\temp\logtest.log
}

$error.Clear()
`

Answer (score 0):

@user10722100 can I ask you for one more hint? My script is bigger. I showed the shorter version because I thought it would be easier. But now I have problem to implement your version :)

```
    $array = @("C:")
    
    foreach ($z in $array) 
        {
            Write-Host "[$((get-date).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd__HH-mm-ss"))] Counting for" $z "..."
            echo '<pre>'
            
            $FileSystemObject = New-Object -com  Scripting.FileSystemObject
            $folders = (Get-Childitem $z -Directory)
            foreach ($folder in $folders)
                {
                    $folder | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "SizeGB" –Value(($FileSystemObject.GetFolder($folder.FullName).Size) / 1GB)
                }
                
            $folders | sort -Property SizeGB -Descending | where {$_.SizeGB -gt 1} | select fullname,@{n=’Size in GB’;e={[math]::Round($_.SizeGB,2)}} | Format-Table -AutoSize
            
            echo '</pre>'
           
            $totalSize = (($folders | Measure-Object 'SizeGB' -Sum).Sum)
            $totalsizeform="{0:N2}" -f $totalSize
            
            echo "Total size for "
            echo '<b>'
            echo $z
            echo '<font color="green">'
            $varia2=": &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" + $totalsizeform + " GB"
            Echo $varia2
            echo '</b><br>'
            echo '<hr />'
            ’’
            echo '</font>'
            
            $suma=$suma+$totalSize
            $sumasum="{0:N2}" -f $suma
        }
```

You have cut out $folders and SizeGB and I don't know how to change that to make it work :-)

Comment: Just updated initial answer to align with your first excerpt. variable name should  be repected and reusable in your version.

Comment: @user10722100 thanks but: `Measure-Object : The property "SizeGB" cannot be found in the input for any objects`. Your code works but I don't get a properly formatted table: `$ folders | table sort -Property SizeGB -Descending | where {$ _. SizeGB -gt 1} | select fullname, @ {n = "Size in GB"; e = {[math] :: Round ($ _. SizeGB, 2)}} | Fo...`. My skills are so weak that I can only afford combinations of this type: `$folder | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "SizeGB" –Value((Get-ChildItem $_.FullName -Recurse | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).Sum)/1Gb`